# [lightbox]Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, lightbox2

I have some JavaScript code that works in FireFox and Chrome . In the Chrome JS Console I get the follow error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

The JavaScript code I am using is:

```
function openBox(str, width, height)
    {
      if(!window.lightbox) {
            window.lightbox = this;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.opacity = 0.1;
            this.refresh = function()
            {
                this.background.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:black;opacity:'+ this.opacity +';z-index:999;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:'+ window.innerWidth +'px;height:'+ window.innerHeight +'px;');
                this.box.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:white;z-index:9999;width:'+ (this.width / this.facteur) +'px;height:'+ (this.height / this.facteur) +'px;position:absolute;top:'+ ((window.innerHeight - (this.height / this.facteur)) / 2) +'px;left:'+ ((window.innerWidth - (this.width / this.facteur)) / 2) +'px;');
            };
            this.fondu = function(facteur)
            {
                if(window.lightbox) {
                    if(facteur == undefined) {
                            facteur = (this.state == 0) ? this.facteur : - this.facteur;
                    } if(Math.abs(facteur) > 1) {       
                        var bfr_facteur = (facteur > 0) ? facteur - 0.1 : facteur + 0.1;;
                        this.opacity = this.opacity * facteur / bfr_facteur;
                        this.width = this.width * facteur / bfr_facteur;
                        this.height = this.height * facteur / bfr_facteur
                        this.refresh();
                        setTimeout(function()
                        {
                            window.lightbox.fondu(bfr_facteur);
                        }, 10);
                    } else {
                        if(this.state == 0) {
                            this.box.appendChild(this.text);
                            this.box.appendChild(this.close);
                            this.state = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            this.background = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(background);
            this.box = document.createElement('div');
            this.box.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:white;z-index:9999;width:'+ (width / 6) +'px;height:'+ (height / 6) +'px;position:absolute;left:'+ (screen.availWidth / 2 - (width / 3)) +'px;top:'+ (screen.availHeight / 2 - (width / 3)) +'px;');
            this.background.appendChild(box);
            this.text = document.createTextNode(str);
            this.close = document.createElement('a');
            this.close.setAttribute('href','#lightbox:close');
            this.close.setAttribute('style','float:right;');   
            this.close.onclick = function() {
                openBox.closeBox();
            }
            this.close.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Close [X]'));
            this.state = 0;
            this.facteur = 6;
            this.fondu();
        }
    }
```

and the input :

```
<a href="#lightbox:Bienvenue" onclick="openBox('Bienvenue sur mon site', 400, 250);return false" ><img src="./ICONE/contacts.png" title="Contacts" width="70" height="70"/>
```

The error is in the line of firste if in methode openBox.

Comment: That code parses just fine (http://jsparse.meteor.com is great for this sort of thing), I think the error must be coming from other code you haven't posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Javascript code :**

```
function openBox(str, width, height)
    {
      if(!window.lightbox) {
            window.lightbox = this;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.opacity = 0.1;
            this.refresh = function()
            {
                this.background.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:black;opacity:'+ this.opacity +';z-index:999;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:'+ window.innerWidth +'px;height:'+ window.innerHeight +'px;');
                this.box.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:white;z-index:9999;width:'+ (this.width / this.facteur) +'px;height:'+ (this.height / this.facteur) +'px;position:absolute;top:'+ ((window.innerHeight - (this.height / this.facteur)) / 2) +'px;left:'+ ((window.innerWidth - (this.width / this.facteur)) / 2) +'px;');
            };
            this.fondu = function(facteur)
            {
                if(window.lightbox) {
                    if(facteur === undefined) {
                            facteur = (this.state === 0) ? this.facteur : - this.facteur;
                    } if(Math.abs(facteur) > 1) {       
                        var bfr_facteur = (facteur > 0) ? facteur - 0.1 : facteur + 0.1;
                        this.opacity = this.opacity * facteur / bfr_facteur;
                        this.width = this.width * facteur / bfr_facteur;
                        this.height = this.height * facteur / bfr_facteur;
                        this.refresh();
                        setTimeout(function()
                        {
                            window.lightbox.fondu(bfr_facteur);
                        }, 10);
                    } else {
                        if(this.state === 0) {
                            this.box.appendChild(this.text);
                            this.box.appendChild(this.close);
                            this.state = 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            this.background = document.createElement('div');
            document.body.appendChild(background);
            this.box = document.createElement('div');
            this.box.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:white;z-index:9999;width:'+ (width / 6) +'px;height:'+ (height / 6) +'px;position:absolute;left:'+ (screen.availWidth / 2 - (width / 3)) +'px;top:'+ (screen.availHeight / 2 - (width / 3)) +'px;');
            this.background.appendChild(box);
            this.text = document.createTextNode(str);
            this.close = document.createElement('a');
            this.close.setAttribute('href','#lightbox:close');
            this.close.setAttribute('style','float:right;');   
            this.close.onclick = function() {
                openBox.closeBox();
            };
            this.close.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Close [X]'));
            this.state = 0;
            this.facteur = 6;
            this.fondu();
        }
    }
```

**input code:**

```
<a href="#lightbox:Bienvenue" onclick="openBox('Bienvenue sur mon site', 400, 250);return false" ></a>
<img src="./ICONE/contacts.png" title="Contacts" width="70" height="70"/>
```

Comment: I cleaned up the code a little there were errors with semicolon

Comment: i have probleme in function : openBox.closeBox();

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in this function caller from `openBox`:

```
openBox.closeBox = function()
    {
        window.lightbox.box.innerHTML = "";
        window.lightbox.fondu();
        document.body.removeChild(window.lightbox.background);
        window.lightbox = null;
    };
```

And my page is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Control</title>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/date.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {

        background-image:url('assets/img/login_bg.png');

      }

      .main {

        width: 98%;

        height: 98%;



        background-color: #ffffff;

        border: 1px solid #999999;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        border-radius: 6px;

        outline: none;

        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);



        position: absolute;

        top: 0;

        bottom: 0;

        left: 0;

        right: 0;



        margin: auto;



        padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;

      }

      .logo {

        margin: 0 0 0 -140px;

        height: 532px;

        width: 200px;

        z-index:-1;

        position: absolute;

      }

      #func td {

        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;

        text-align: center;

      }

      .map {

        width: 100%;

        height: 82%;

        margin-bottom: 5px;

      }

      #files td {

        padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;

        text-align: center;

      }

      .row {

        margin: 0 0 -5px 0;

      }

      .fullwidth {

        width: 100%;

        min-width: 135px;

      }

      .halfwidth {

        width: 48%;

      }

      .addselection {

        min-width: 30px;

      }

      .devicestable {

        border: 1px solid #999999;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        border-radius: 6px;

        margin-bottom: 5px;

      }

      .functionslist {

        border: 1px solid #999999;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        border-radius: 6px;

        margin-bottom: 5px;

      }

      .messageboxcontainer {

        border: 1px solid #999999;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        border-radius: 6px;

        min-height: 185px;

        max-height: 39%;

        /* position: absolute; */

      }

      .filestable {

        border: 1px solid #999999;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        border-radius: 6px;

        min-height: 185px;

        max-height: 185px;

        padding-top: 5px;

      }

      .mapcontainer {

        border: 1px solid #999999;

        border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        border-radius: 6px;

        min-height: 185px;

        max-height: 39%;

        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;

        /* position: absolute; */

      }

      input {

        text-align: center;

      }

    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>

var map;

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {

    zoom: 0,

    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0),

    disableDefaultUI: true,

    panControl: false,

    zoomControl: true,

    scaleControl: false,

    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID

  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),

      mapOptions);

}



google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



    </script>



    <script>

    var selected=new Array();



    var markersArray = [];



    function gmapsmarker(location1, location2, title) {

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: new google.maps.LatLng(location1, location2),

        map: map,

        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

        title: title

      });

      markersArray.push(marker);

    }



    function deleteOverlays() {

      if (markersArray) {

        for (i in markersArray) {

          markersArray[i].setMap(null);

        }

        markersArray.length = 0;

      }

    }



    function deleteMarker(deltitle) {

      return markersArray.indexOf(deltitle);

    }



    function select(bot, lat, longi) {

      if (document.getElementById(bot).innerHTML == '-') {

        document.getElementById(bot).innerHTML = '+';

        for(var i in selected){

          if(selected[i]==bot){

            selected.splice(i,1);

            break;

          }

        }

        document.getElementById("selectednumber").innerHTML = selected.length;

        if (selected.length==0) {

          document.getElementById("selectednumber").setAttribute("data-original-title", "None Selected");

          deleteOverlays();

        } else {

          document.getElementById("selectednumber").setAttribute("data-original-title", selected.join(', '));

        }

      } else {

      if (selected.indexOf(bot) == -1) {

        selected.push(bot);

      }

      document.getElementById(bot).innerHTML = '-';

      document.getElementById("selectednumber").innerHTML = selected.length;

      document.getElementById("selectednumber").setAttribute("data-original-title", selected.join(', '));

      gmapsmarker(lat, longi, bot);

      }

    }



    function clearselection() {

      for (var i=0;i<selected.length;i++) {

        document.getElementById(selected[i]).innerHTML = '+';

      }

      selected.length = 0;

      document.getElementById("selectednumber").innerHTML = selected.length;

      document.getElementById("selectednumber").setAttribute("data-original-title", "None Selected");

      deleteOverlays();

    }



    function selectall() {

      selected = $("div.addbuttons > button").map(function(){

        return this.id;

      }).get();

      var index = selected.indexOf(" ");

      selected.splice(index, 1);

      var index2 = selected.indexOf("");

      selected.splice(index2, 1);

      for (var i=0;i<selected.length;i++) {

        document.getElementById(selected[i]).onclick();

      }

      document.getElementById("selectednumber").innerHTML = selected.length;

      document.getElementById("selectednumber").setAttribute("data-original-title", selected.join(', '));

    }



    function getHistory(uid) {

      if (uid=="") {

        document.getElementById("historyof").innerHTML = "All Bots";

      } else {

        document.getElementById("historyof").innerHTML = uid;

      }

      var xmlhttp;

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

          document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }

      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","getmessages.php?uid="+uid,true);

      xmlhttp.send();

    }



    function addCommand(command, arg1, arg2) {

      var xmlhttp;

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

          if (xmlhttp.responseText=="Success"){

            alert("Command Added");

          } else {

            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

          }

        }

      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","addcommand.php?uid="+selected+"&command="+command+"&arg1="+arg1+"&arg2="+arg2,true);

      xmlhttp.send();

    }



    var refresh;



    var scroll;



    <?php if($autoscrolltextbox){ echo "scroll='auto'"; } else { echo "scroll='manual'"; } ?>



    function updateScroll() {

      if (scroll=='auto'){

        scroll='manual';

        document.getElementById("autoscrollbutton").innerHTML="Auto Scroll: Off";

      } else {

        scroll='auto';

        document.getElementById("autoscrollbutton").innerHTML="Auto Scroll: On";

      }

    }



    function autoScroll(){

      if (scroll=='auto'){

        var elem = document.getElementById('messagebox');

        elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;

      } else {



      }

    }



    function autorefresh(uid) {

      refresh = setInterval(function() { getHistory(uid); autoScroll(); }, <?php echo $messageboxrefreshspeed; ?>);

    }



    function stoprefresh() {

      window.clearInterval(window.refresh);

    }



    function viewCommands() {

      stoprefresh();

      var xmlhttp;

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

          document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

        }

      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","getwaitingcommands.php",true);

      xmlhttp.send();

    }



    function fixSelected() {

            $.each(selected, function(index, value) {

                document.getElementById(value).innerHTML = '-';

            });

    }



    function refreshTable() {

        $('#tablefill').load('table.php', function(){

          fixSelected();

        });

    }



    function refreshFileTable() {

        $('#filetablefill').load('filetable.php', function(){

        });

    }



    function refreshImages() {

        $('#replaceimages').load('showpictures.php?uid='+uid, function(){

          var sliderval=document.getElementById('defaultSlider').value;

          $('.getimgimg').width(sliderval+'px');

        });

    }



    function getImages() {

      uid = $("#modaluid").val();

      startdate = $("#modalstarttime").val();

      enddate = $("#modalendtime").val();

      filesize = $("#modalfilesize").val();



      fixstartdate = Date.parse(startdate).getTime()/1000;

      fixenddate = Date.parse(enddate).getTime()/1000;



      var xmlhttp;

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

        }

      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","getimages.php?uid="+uid+"&start="+fixstartdate+"&end="+fixenddate+"&filesize="+filesize,true);

      xmlhttp.send();

      refreshImages();

      imgrefresh = setInterval(refreshImages, 2000);

    }



    function deletePics(uid) {

      var xmlhttp;

      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {

        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

          alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

        }

      }

      xmlhttp.open("GET","deletepics.php?uid="+uid,true);

      xmlhttp.send();

    }



$(function(){



    $('#defaultSlider').change(function(){

        $('.getimgimg').width(this.value);

    });



    $('#defaultSlider').change();



});

    </script>



     <script src="assets/js/lightbox/lightbox.js"></script>
     <script src="assets/js/lightbox/lightbox.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

         if ($("[rel=tooltip]").length) {

             $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();

         }

         refreshTable();

         refreshFileTable();

         getHistory("");

         autorefresh("");

         setInterval(refreshTable, <?php echo $devicestablerefreshspeed; ?>);

         setInterval(refreshFileTable, <?php echo $filestablerefreshspeed; ?>);

     });


     function openBox(str, width, height)
        {
          if(!window.lightbox) {
                window.lightbox = this;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                this.opacity = 0.1;
                this.refresh = function()
                {
                    this.background.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:black;opacity:'+ this.opacity +';z-index:999;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:'+ window.innerWidth +'px;height:'+ window.innerHeight +'px;');
                    this.box.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:white;z-index:9999;width:'+ (this.width / this.facteur) +'px;height:'+ (this.height / this.facteur) +'px;position:absolute;top:'+ ((window.innerHeight - (this.height / this.facteur)) / 2) +'px;left:'+ ((window.innerWidth - (this.width / this.facteur)) / 2) +'px;');
                };
                this.fondu = function(facteur)
                {
                    if(window.lightbox) {
                        if(facteur == undefined) {
                                facteur = (this.state == 0) ? this.facteur : - this.facteur;
                        } if(Math.abs(facteur) > 1) {       
                            var bfr_facteur = (facteur > 0) ? facteur - 0.1 : facteur + 0.1;;
                            this.opacity = this.opacity * facteur / bfr_facteur;
                            this.width = this.width * facteur / bfr_facteur;
                            this.height = this.height * facteur / bfr_facteur
                            this.refresh();
                            setTimeout(function()
                            {
                                window.lightbox.fondu(bfr_facteur);
                            }, 10);
                        } else {
                            if(this.state == 0) {
                                this.box.appendChild(this.text);
                                this.box.appendChild(this.close);
                                this.state = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
                this.background = document.createElement('div');
                document.body.appendChild(background);
                this.box = document.createElement('div');
                this.box.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:white;z-index:9999;width:'+ (width / 6) +'px;height:'+ (height / 6) +'px;position:absolute;left:'+ (screen.availWidth / 2 - (width / 3)) +'px;top:'+ (screen.availHeight / 2 - (width / 3)) +'px;');
                this.background.appendChild(box);
                this.text = document.createTextNode(str);
                this.close = document.createElement('a');
                this.close.setAttribute('href','#lightbox:close');
                this.close.setAttribute('style','float:right;');   
                this.close.onclick = function() {
                    openBox.closeBox();
                }
                this.close.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Close [X]'));
                this.state = 0;
                this.facteur = 6;
                this.fondu();
            }
        }
        openBox.closeBox = function()
        {
            window.lightbox.box.innerHTML = "";
            window.lightbox.fondu();
            document.body.removeChild(window.lightbox.background);
            window.lightbox = null;
        };


    </script>

  </head>

  <body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    <div class="main">

      <div class="row" style="height:60%;">

        <div class="col-lg-9 devicestable" style="height:100%; min-height:380px; padding-top: 5px; overflow:auto;">

           <div id="tablefill"></div>

        </div>

  <div class="modal fade" id="imageModal">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

          <h4 class="modal-title">View Images</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <p>UID</p>

          <input class="form-control input-small" id="modaluid" type="text" value="">

          <p>Start Date</p>

          <input class="form-control input-small" id="modalstarttime" type="date" placeholder="Start Date">

          <p>End Date</p>

          <input class="form-control input-small" id="modalendtime" type="date" placeholder="End Date">

          <p>Max File Size</p>

          <input class="form-control input-small" id="modalfilesize" type="text" placeholder="Max File Size in MB">

        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#displayImages" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="getImages();">View Images</button>

        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="displayImages">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">

          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

          <h4 style="display:inline;" class="modal-title">Images</h4>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="defaultSlider" type="range" min="100" max="520" />

        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">

          <div id="replaceimages"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.clearInterval(window.imgrefresh);" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

        <div class="col-lg-3 functionslist" style="height:100%; min-height:400px; padding-top: 5px; overflow:auto;">

          <table class="table" id="func">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <!-- contact -->    
                <div><a href="#lightbox:Bienvenue" onclick="openBox('Bienvenue sur mon site', 400, 250);return false" ><img src="./ICONE/contacts.png" title="Contacts" width="70" height="70"/></a></div>
                <!-- <button type="button" 
                onclick="addCommand('ringervolumeup')" class="btn btn-default btn-small fullwidth">Ringer Up</button> -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() 
        { 
            $("#files").tablesorter();
        } 
    );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```